# Convert QString to Local8bit then Converted String to QString

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

How can i convert this to local8bit then converted string to QString:

```
QString m = QString::FromStdString("ÃšÂ©Ã™?Ã™?Ã˜Â§Ã˜Âª Ã™?Ã˜Â±Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â¨Ã˜Â·(0):<BR> <BR><HR><BR><BR><A href='bword://0'>Ã˜Â¨Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â²ÃšÂ¯Ã˜Â´Ã˜Âª Ã˜Â¨Ã™? Ã™?Ã˜Â§Ãš?Ã™? 0</A></B><BR><BR><HR><BR><A href='bword://latitude (l,0)'>latitude (l,0)</A> <BR> <B><A href='bword://logical 0 state'>logical 0 state</A> </B><BR><BR><HR>   0   ");code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the following functions:

```
std::string str = m.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

and vice versa

```
QString m = QString::fromLocal8Bit("SomeText in Local");
```